# How to check the default buildkit version?

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

## Background

I want to check if my current docker setup with BuildKit contains [this commit](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/2089/commits/aa467196bdd5a5d8dd4fe805d590906d81619cdb).

## Question

How do I find out what BuildKit versions docker uses when I build an image with

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update**: as commented by @N1ngu, if you're doing these steps on recent versions (>= 22), check `vendor.mod` instead of `vendor.conf`.

I don't think it does. My Docker version is pretty recent (20.10.12) and has a buildkit version that precedes that. Here's what I did to try to check:

1. Get the commit id for my current version of docker:

```
$docker --version
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed5707e
```

2. Find [the commit on github](https://github.com/docker/cli/commit/e91ed5707e) (or locally if you clone the repo)
3. Check the commit specified for buildkit on [vendor.conf for that version](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/e91ed5707e038b02af3b5120fa0835c5bedfd42e/vendor.conf):

```
github.com/moby/buildkit                            8142d66b5ebde79846b869fba30d9d30633e74aa # v0.8.1
```

4. [Compare these commits on buildkit's repository](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/compare/8142d66b5ebde79846b869fba30d9d30633e74aa...aa46719). On this page, you can see that 8142d66, the version Docker 20.10.12 bundles, precedes aa46719. If it was the opposite, the comparison tool would the branch as up-to-date, like what happens if you [invert the commits in the URL](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/compare/aa46719...8142d66b5ebde79846b869fba30d9d30633e74aa).

Comment: As the aftermath of https://github.com/docker/cli/commit/7e560ae76fd07908fa4c64fb70dc6a0d2162be20 `vendor.mod` should be checked instead of `vendor.conf`

Comment: Thanks! I'll add that note at the top.

Answer (score 8):

An easier way to see what version of BuildKit is running on docker is to run

```
$ docker buildx ls    
NAME/NODE   DRIVER/ENDPOINT STATUS  BUILDKIT             PLATFORMS
  default   default         running v0.11.7+d3e6c1360f6e linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386
```